# Derive Gibbs sampler for exponential state space model

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I have a hidden Markov model.

$X_n = e^{-b\times dt}\times X_{n-1} + \sigma_v \times V_v$

$Y_n = X_n + \sigma_w \times V_w$

where $b$ is the model parameter, $\sigma_w$ is the standard deviation following Gaussian noise. How to find the conditional probability of $b$ given $X$ and $Y$ from $n \in {1,2,\dots, k}$?

I think I need to use the log-normal as the $\log(\sigma)$ returns a negative value. Can anyone provide a detailed derivation?

Comment: 1. The way your model is written, $Y_n$ is irrelevant; if I'm given $X$, $Y$ contains no information.  2.  If $dt$ is constant, which, given that you are incrementing your indices by $1$ and $dt$ is not indexed at all, then you have $X_n = aX_{n-1} + e_n$, where $a = \exp\{-bdt\}$.  If you calculate an estimate of $a$, you can easily transform that to an estimate of $b$.  Even if $dt$ varies, however, as long as it's known it's straightforward.

Comment: I want to derive a Gibbs sampler from the state space model. How to find the distribution to sample from for a?